# Coupon Codes for product discount combined with conditional free shipping

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, e-commerce

I have done some research on product discount coupons that also allow conditional shipping discounts when I was approached with the following request:

**“We are going to provide customers with a coupon code that gives them 25% off a product purchase and free shipping…….IF they live in the continental United States. If they live in Canada, Alaska or Hawaii they get the 25% discount but there is an additional shipping charge of $50.00”**

If someone has had experience with a request like this I would be interested in hearing what options are available to have this type of control on coupon codes and shipping.

```
Woocommerce Version:    3.4.5
WordPress: 4.9.8

Plugins (related to Coupons and Shipping):
WooCommerce Coupon Shortcodes       by itthinx – 1.6.2
WooCommerce - ShipStation Integration       by WooCommerce – 4.1.22
WooCommerce Subscriptions       by Prospress Inc. – 2.2.21 – 2.4.4 is available
WooCommerce Table Rate Shipping     by WooCommerce – 3.0.9 – 3.0.12 is available
WooCommerce     by Automattic – 3.4.5 – 3.5.1 is available
```

**Current Coupon and Shipping setup:**

```
We currently use 2 shipping zones. 

1. Continental US =  $35
2. Canada, Alaska and Hawaii = $85

With Coupon Code: 40NoShip
The customer should get 40% off a product 
and the following shipping cost.

1. Continental US =  $0
2. Canada, Alaska and Hawaii = $50
```

Our problem is the coupon code when created using Woocommerce Coupons only has the option to provide free shipping. But the small print tells the customer there is still a fee for delivers outside of the Continental US. So how do we still charge the $50 fee for products shipped outside the Continental US?

If there is any other information I can provide please let me know.

Comment: You can create different shipping zones and add the shipping methods accordingly.

Comment: @Akshat please see the additional information I provided about our current shipping zones and how they relate to my question. I hope this additional info helps. Thanks.